# What do the RED numbers on the Gnome Files Dock Icon mean?

Tags: gnome, dock

I can't find any explanation for the red numbers on the Files icon in my Ubuntu dock. What is this trying to tell me? It looks like this:

[image: image of the Files Dock icon with a Red Circle around the number 2 in white letters]

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 with the Ubuntu dock extension enabled.

Comment: This is normal ubuntu behaviour(The purpose of it is to notify the user how many jobs have been done or any notification sent).

Comment: AFAIK you have to fork the [dash-to-dock](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock) project and modify the code such that this doesn't happen. Then install the newly created plugin.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464618/do-green-numbers-on-icons-in-the-dock-mean-i-should-be-doing-something

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04. To disable this number, It was my solution: setting -> notifications, select 'files' -> and set off 'notifications'

Comment: Thanks Carlos. That was very simple and I don't know why I didn't think of that myself! I can't, for the life of me, think what it's trying to notify me about, though. Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue on Manjaro gnome, disable the "show icon emblems" option on dash to dock settings

Answer (score 0):

if you select on the clock on the middle of the screen at the top, it will show the calendar and the notifications. Likely there is a notification from the files. Select that, then you will clear the notification. The number should vanish after that.