# Do green numbers on icons in the dock mean I should be doing something?

Tags: upgrade, dock, 23.04

I just now upgraded from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 23.04 using the GUI upgrade tool.
Since the upgrade, little green circles with numbers have appeared in the upper right corner of some of the icons in the Dock. For example:

- The Files icon has a green circle with '3' in it, even when I don't have a Files folder open.
- Firefox does not have any green circle/number on it when it is not open, but when I run a single instance of Firefox a green '2' appears.
- Calculator does not have any green circle/number on it at any time, whether it is open/running or not.

[image: Here's a partial screenshot of my Ubuntu Dock, showing the green circles and numbers this post is about]

In a search, I have not been able to find documentation of this.
The behaviour is a little like what is described in this user's question: [What do the RED numbers on the Gnome Files Dock Icon mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459762/what-do-the-red-numbers-on-the-gnome-files-dock-icon-mean)
...but the numbers are not consistent with the number of GUI windows I have open and are not shown at all for some apps.

Please could the community advise:

1. What do these numbers mean?
2. If they mean I'm supposed to do something, then what do I do to address that 'something'?
3. If they are not useful, how do I turn them off?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Those are notifications.

Click on the date/time to see them.

Comment: What "notifications" does the file manager give?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I had one saying that the SD card drive was removed.

Comment: Great example!!

Comment: Thank you!! Following your advice I discovered old notifications for USB storage devices being removed (the File notifications) and a notification that Snap wanted me to close Firefox to do an update. Once I'd cleared those notifications, the green circles/numbers went away as would be expected.

Comment: Where is the date/time? In the Dock? When I open the Files program? I don't see any more green circles when I open the Files application.

Comment: Thanks. After clicking on the date/time, I saw that there was a "Do Not Disturb" switch. I turned it on, and hey presto: no more green circles!

Comment: Also there is a button to clear notifications.

Comment: You know it's confusing UX when you end up on "askubuntu"..... they should at least have a tooltip to say what it is!